# jQuery .each not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I have this ajax code below which is returning a List of products of a specific category ID which is passed in the data :

THe list is then looped through and displayed one by one.

The code below works in both chrome and firefox, but in IE9 it will only display the first product.

```
function getProducts(catID) {
$('#ChangeContent').html('');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Mainpage.aspx/GetProducts",
    data: "{categoryID:" + catID + " }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        allProducts = msg.d;

        $.each(msg.d, function (i, value) {

                var desc = "";
                if (value.description.length > 70) {
                    desc = value.description.substring(0, 67);
                    desc += " ...";
                }
                else {
                    desc = value.description;
                }
                var htmll = "<div class='OutsideDiv' onclick='displayProduct(" + value.productID + " )'><table class='DivBorder'>  <tr > <td class='imageBox'><img alt='' src='" + value.image + "' /></td>  </tr> <tr >  <td class='title'>" + value.name + "</td>";
                htmll += "   </tr> <tr>  <td class='desc'>" + desc + " </td> </tr>  <tr> <td class='price'>€" + value.price + "</td>  </tr> </table></div>";
                htmll += " <script type='text/javascript'>$('.DivBorder').mouseover(function (){$(this).css('border-color', '#cb510a');$(this).css('background-color', '#e2e2e2');});$('.DivBorder').mouseout(function (){$(this).css('border-color', '#bdbdbd');$(this).css('background-color', '#f6f6f6');});";

                $('#ChangeContent').append(htmll);

            });

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Errorrrrrr");
    }
});
```

};

I did try searching for this problem, but couldnt find this same problem which includes .each inside .ajax

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's no problem with `$.each()` in IE9. If it only iterates the first item, then that likely means theres some error causing the code to halt. Check your developer console.

Comment: ...maybe because the `<script>` element you're appending has no closing `</script>`. Why are you appending a script like that anyway? You're going to bind the same events to the same `.DivBorder` elements over and over again.

Comment: Yep, that was it, the </script> closing tag, I forgot to add it after removing part of that string. I had to append the script like that because when I put the mouseover, mouseout code in an external .js file they were not being fired. Whats your suggestion to eliminate that part of script appending and leave just html?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use HTML to create the elements. But even if you do, one way to do it is to create the elements, do the append, then bind the handler to the specific element. Like `$(htmll).appendTo("#ChangeContent").find(".DivBorder").on("mouseover", function() {... ` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...maybe because the  element you're appending has no closing
>   . Why are you appending a script like that anyway? You're
>   going to bind the same events to the same .DivBorder elements over and
>   over again.

As cookie monster said